# How to import import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row error?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache, maven-jar-plugin

I am tring to write data into Excel using Apache

i refer this link:https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

**Cell and Row are not Importing**

[image: Cell and Row are not Importing]

**This my java class code:**

[image]

I download [Apache jar file here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9)

MY java code below:

```
 try {
            String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
            Object[][] datatypes = {
                                  {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
                                  {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                                  {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                                  {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                                  {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                                  {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixesize"}
                          };
                int rowNum = 0;
                System.out.println("Creating excel");

                          for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
                              Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                              int colNum = 0;
                              for (Object field : datatype) {
                                  Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                                  if (field instanceof String) {
                                      cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                                  } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                                      cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
                          workbook.write(outputStream);
                          workbook.close();


                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
}
```

**Build.gridle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You will need at least https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9 too.

Comment: @Axel Richter i already add same lib sir.

Comment: Sure? Seems you have only `<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>` but not `<artifactId>poi</artifactId>`.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you sir,let me check please wait sir,

Comment: @AxelRichter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297250/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-apache-xmlbean/46297474#46297474 Please look at this sir my new question..i am facing new problem now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple You need to add the **jar** file

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9

Go to this link download the **jar file** Add it in your **lib** folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```
String filepath = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";

    FileInputStream fis;

    fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the above code, Use XSSFRow instead of Row:

```
XSSFRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
```

Comment: Please give a more elaborate response.
And you should write the code appropriately.