# error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;

Tags: java, android, excel, apache, lib

I am tring to write data into Excel using Apache,i am getting error in this line      **XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()**;I posted my error log below please check.

```
 Process: app.msupply.com.ideaurben, PID: 28508
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:53)
at app.msupply.com.ideaurben.Adapter.ReportcateorieslistAdapter$MyViewHolder$2.onResponse(ReportcateorieslistAdapter.java:384)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.msupply.com.ideaurben-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.msupply.com.ideaurben-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:53) 
at app.msupply.com.ideaurben.Adapter.ReportcateorieslistAdapter$MyViewHolder$2.onResponse(ReportcateorieslistAdapter.java:384) 
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

my **libs** folder: i add all the library in libs folder.
[image]

**My java class Code:**

```
    try {

            String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/MyFirstExcel.xlsx";
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");
          Object[][] datatypes = {
                  {"Datatype", "Type", "Size(in bytes)"},
                  {"int", "Primitive", 2},
                  {"float", "Primitive", 4},
                  {"double", "Primitive", 8},
                  {"char", "Primitive", 1},
                  {"String", "Non-Primitive", "No fixed size"}
          };
          int rowNum = 0;
          System.out.println("Creating excel");
          Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
          for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
              Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
              int colNum = 0;
              for (Object field : datatype) {
                  Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                  if (field instanceof String) {
                      cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                  } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                      cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                  }
              }
          }
          FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
          workbook.write(outputStream);
        //  workbook.close();


      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } /*catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }*//*catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }*/

  }
```

**Build.gradel** file as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.msupply.com.ideaurben"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

please help anyone,Thanks in advance.

Comment: you get this error when the class cannot be found at runtime, please make sure you are not missing the poi-ooxml-3-9.jar at runtime.

Comment: I add `poi-ooxml-3-9.jar` library in my lib folder sir.

Comment: workbook.close(); is also  not recognizing my java class sir..so i commented that line

Comment: `workbook.close();` this line showing compile time error. so i comment that line as of now.

Comment: You need https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.9 `<artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>` and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.3.0 and probably https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/3.9 `<artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>` too.

Comment: Thank you very much sir,,,i know this is some lib problem.....i will try  sir then,if i face any problem i will inform you,,

Comment: @Axel Richter i need to remove all jar file replace your file.i'm correct sir.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions` still this same error is occures.

Comment: You are missing `xmlbeans` jar (I've linked in my previous comment). An you need all the jars. So not removing the others. But since you tagged `android` a look at https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ maybe the better approach.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you sir it's solved now.post as Answer i will accept your answer.But now file is not creating now different problem `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/IDEA FILES/MyFirstExcel.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`..

Comment: No.The question is: "What exact dependencies are needed for using `apache poi`?". And I will not answer that question because the `apache poi` dependencies are a mess and so this question is not to answer in general. And it is not to answer for `android` in special since `andoid` has a amputated `Java` only. But your new problem is clear: Your code has not permissions to open the `Excel` file.

Comment: oh Ok sry sir,i add all permission in manifest file.`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`even though it's showing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154849/discussion-between-mariyappan-and-axel-richter).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to correct the perspective of others on NoClassDefFoundError.

NoClassDefFoundError can occur for multiple reasons like

1. `ClassNotFoundException` -- .class not found for that referenced class irrespective of whether it is available at compile time or not(i.e base/child class).
2. Class file located, but Exception raised while initializing static variables
3. Class file located, Exception raised while initializing static blocks

What it means by saying "available in compile time"?

- The referenced class is used in the code. 
  Eg: Two classes, A and B(extends A). If B is referenced directly in the code, it is available at compile time, i.e. `A a = new B();`

What it means by saying "not available at compile time"?

- The compile time class and runtime class are different, i.e. for example base class is loaded using classname of child class for example Class.forName("classname")
  Eg: Two classes, A and B(extends A). Code has

  A a = Class.forName("B").newInstance();

Comment: error showing in this line  `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Comment: This does not appear to contain a solution to the problem described in the question; could you edit it to add one?